# Using proxy_pass as an error page in location Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am configuring Nginx to serve two different locations. Idea is to serve the `localhost:3000` as default and if the page not found in that location then try to use the other location as a fallback. But is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name server.in;

    ssl_certificate /junk/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /junk/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

    index index.html;

    recursive_error_pages on;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location /  {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        error_page 404 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need `proxy_intercept_errors on;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors).

Comment: @RichardSmith Still not working. What should be the context it server or location ??